# Task clean FAILED on gradlew clean RNN

Tags: react-native, gradlew

When I try to `gradlew clean` my rn project, get this error at first time:

`> Task :@kyivstarteam_react-native-sms-user-consent:clean FAILED`

But this does not happen in the second try and clean successful.

What is the problem? or Does this cause a problem?